# Issue with MailItem Size

Tags: c++, mfc, outlook

I'm working on a MFC applications that captures some Outlook events including `Application.Send` and `Items.ItemAdd` events. When an email is sent I save it in order to get its size (when I don't, the size is always 0). I noticed that the size is different from the one I get after ItemAdd event is raised. Is this a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal - by the time the message ends up in your Sent Items folder, its has all the sender related properties added to it.